# Tween library for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

Could someone recommend me of a good Tween library for AS3 (for use with Flash, not Flex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tween Lite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) is supposed to be good; My good-at-flash-friends recommanded it to me. What I found useful that it provided a little flash-app for trying out the different tweens and generating the code snippet for the choosen tween in the same time.

Comment: I've had only good experiences with TweenLite. The plugins make a lot of common tasks (and eye candy!) very easy to do.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a short list of tween libraries I'm quite familiar with:

- [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)
- [GTween](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/)
- [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)
- [Eaze](http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/)

And, here's a link to a nice comparison of a suite of different libraries for both AS2 and AS3: http://www.greensock.com/tweening-speed-test/

Ultimately, it's going to come down to which syntax you prefer and which one you're most comfortable with. I suggest you look a few of them over, pick one or two and code up an easy comparison to see for yourself...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've always found greensock so easy to fall into - it gives you a great script generator with a list of all it can do.