# What current library is needed to animate a movie clip with actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tween library for AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442191/tween-library-for-as3)

I have been out of ActionScript programming for a few years now and I am trying to create a simple sliding door animation with AS3. I used to use Tweener for all of this but noticed the library has not been updated since 2009 and want to know what current library allows for ActionScript animations? (Or perhaps people are still using the older libraries...)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @32bitkid you're over 4096 reputation, time to change your name. ;)

Comment: the greensock libraries are under a proprietary license and you'll get nailed if you use them in a commercial application. I advise that you stick with Tweener. Just because it hasn't been updated does not mean it is not good. Sometimes there just isn't anything more to add to a library.

Comment: @AscensionSystems Actually Greensock charges no fee as long as you are not charging end users of the application they are in. At least for TweenLight, it is in the FAQ.

Comment: Also, question is closed... I guess it is similar, but that question is still 2 years old. Part of my question was I wanted to know current libraries that are well written and effective because everything I was finding was at least two years old.

Comment: I'm still lost as to where you're drawing the conclusion that an old library is a bad library...

Comment: @AscensionSystems I am not saying an old library is bad. It is old, and can easily be outdated. When the thread has been dead for 2 years, you have no way of knowing if it is still a good library to use from the postings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Greensock's TweenMax, TweenLite and TweenNano](http://www.greensock.com/) are the best in my opinion.

Comment: Ran across these shortly before you posted. They are working slick.